# Reset page vertical space on top?

Tags: vertical-alignment

This is one of the cases, where I've tried for some time now to come up with a minimal example that will demonstrate the problem, but I can't. All I can provide is the problematic behavior of the master document, so I hope you'll bear with me.

Essentially, I use `titlesec` for custom headings; and `pdfpages` to include PDF pages. I have a structure like:

```
\includepdf{...}
\cleardoublepage

\tracingpages=1
mysection*{Section X} \tracingpages=0

% rest of content...
```

When it's like this, all is good, and I can confirm that all sections are positioned at the same location on the page (*EDIT: a good explanation of the `\tracingpages` log is in [#60213 - How can I create a chapter with graphics only divided into different sections?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60213/2595)*):

```bsh
$ grep '^%' mydocument.log

%% goal height=591.5302, max depth=5.5
% t=14.4 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=-10.76009 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=-300 c=100000#
% t=35.31354 plus 0.15234 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
%% goal height=591.5302, max depth=5.5
% t=0.0 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=14.4 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=-10.76009 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=-300 c=100000#
% t=35.31354 plus 0.15234 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
%% goal height=591.5302, max depth=5.5
% t=14.4 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=-10.76009 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=-300 c=100000#
% t=35.31354 plus 0.15234 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
%% goal height=591.5302, max depth=5.5
% t=14.4 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=-10.76009 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=-300 c=100000#
% t=35.31354 plus 0.15234 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
```

So, all sections end at top position t=35.31354, and they are indeed aligned fine.

The problem is, sometimes `\cleardoublepage` inserts a blank page **twice**. 
If the included pdf ends on odd page, then `\cleardoublepage` correctly inserts a blank page, and new section starts on next odd. 
If the included pdf ends on even page, then I get a blank on (next) odd page; `\cleardoublepage` apparently picks this up, and inserts one more as even - and the new section starts on (next+2) odd page.

So if I remove `\cleardoublepage` from a spot like that, then the next "Section X" starts at the next page after PDF is finished, and is on an odd page, as expected - but now the title is slightly misplaced vertically ( `:/` ) ; here is what the log reports:

```bsh
%% goal height=591.5302, max depth=5.5
% t=14.4 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=-10.76009 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=-300 c=100000#
% t=35.31354 plus 0.15234 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
%% goal height=591.5302, max depth=5.5
% t=0.0 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=14.4 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=-10.76009 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=-300 c=100000#
% t=35.31354 plus 0.15234 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
# NOTE NO 'goal height' HERE!!
% t=40.68004 plus 4.0 minus 6.0 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=15.51996 plus 4.0 minus 6.0 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=-300 c=100000#
% t=61.59358 plus 4.15234 minus 6.0 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
%% goal height=591.5302, max depth=5.5
% t=14.4 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=-10.76009 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=-300 c=100000#
% t=35.31354 plus 0.15234 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
```

So obviously the third listed part is the problematic one:

- There is no `%% goal height` - as if a new page never started;
- The first top position reported is `40.68004 plus 4.0 minus 6.0`, unlike the others being 14.4
- The top then seems to "reset" itself to 15.51996 - but it needs to be on -10.76009 to align like the others.

To me, the problematic part looks like a state, as if we're "currently" on top of a blank page; yet latex still thinks of it as not a new page.

Note that I'm not keen on using `\vspace{-Xpt}` or similar to manually correct, since I'd have to tune the value by hand, and the master document takes several minutes to build... (*and what guarantee do I have that all eventual problematic sections will be misplaced by the same ammount?*)

---

So is there a command I could use, that could "reset" the "current page", so that the "top position" would be reset to a default value (<sub>as a side effect, I'd expect if you use such a command on a page that is typeset halfways, that the "cursor" would essentially go up, and typeset over existing contents</sub>)

---

PS: As an experiment, I tried to get the last statements from `\newpage`:

```
$ texdef -t latex -c book \newpage -f
\newpage is defined by (La)TeX.

\newpage:
macro:->\if@noskipsec \ifx \@nodocument \relax \leavevmode \global \@noskipsecfalse \fi \fi \if@inlabel \leavevmode \global \@inlabelfalse \fi \if@nobreak \@nobreakfalse \everypar {}\fi \par \vfil \penalty -\@M
```

... and add them instead of the problematic `\cleardoublepage`, in hope that they might "reset" the page without breaking it - however, even just `\penalty -\@M` on the problematic spot inserts a new blank page (*and also `\leavevmode` at the same position does nothing to remedy the position*)

Comment: You write that "The problem is, sometimes `\cleardoublepage` inserts a blank page twice." Please provide an MWE (minimum working example) that replicates this problem behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Mico - unfortunately, as I already stated, I tried coming up with an MWE, but I cannot replicate the problem with an MWE... I did come up with some sort of a solution (posted [below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61080/2595)) - but I'd still like to know if there is a single command that can "reset" the top position of current page, without inserting a page break. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, FWIW (without a proper MWE), I fixed my problem with `\unskip` (as I heard somewhere it resets skips), and `\vspace*` - but the question for a command that "resets the top" still stands.

First, I tried inserting an `\unskip` instead of the problematic `\cleardoublepage`; that produced "problematic" page section measurements of:

```
% t=28.68004 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=3.51996 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=-300 c=100000#
% t=49.59358 plus 0.15234 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
```

So, I get a `3.51996` (nicely, without `plus` or `minus` components); and for proper alignment, I should have `-10.76009`; so I take I need 3.51996-(-10.76009) offset upwards, so I simply enter this sequence instead of the problematic `\cleardoublepage`:

```
...
\unskip
\vspace*{-14.28pt}
...
```

... and now the (final) page measurements are:

```
% t=14.40004 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=-10.76004 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=-300 c=100000#
% t=35.31358 plus 0.15234 g=591.5302 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
```

There is but 0.0004 pt difference, and visually I cannot see it - so I'm ok with this.

Another thing is that the mentioned `\mysection` is actually a `titlesec` custom sectioning command; and another thing I didn't mention above, is that the sequence more accurately looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\SetMyVar}[1]{%
\def\MyVar{#1} % 
}

...

\includepdf{...}
\cleardoublepage

\SetMyVar{1}
\tracingpages=1
mysection*{Section X} \tracingpages=0

....
```

(yes, the `\SetMyVar` macro *is* that trivial - it's simply for syntactic consistency with other macros I use)

Now this is the trick - if I replaced the `\cleardoublepage` "as is" - like this:

```
\includepdf{...}
\unskip
\vspace*{-14.28pt}

\SetMyVar{1}
\tracingpages=1
mysection*{Section X} \tracingpages=0
```

... I could in fact not see any expected displacement in the logfile! However, when I then placed the `\cleardoublepage` replacement *after* the `\SetMyVar` macro call:

```
\includepdf{...}

\SetMyVar{1}
\unskip
\vspace*{-14.28pt}
\tracingpages=1
mysection*{Section X} \tracingpages=0
```

... then finally it started working - and I got the (final) page measurements mentioned above.

I still wish I could reset with a command, instead of "compensating" "manually"  - but as long as this approach keeps on working, I'll be happy `:)`

Hope this may help someone,
Cheers!